# Insert data on a Array, big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with the following structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru1jW.png)

I am trying to insert data using the following query:

INSERT INTO
`PROJECT.dataset.table`(
paragraphs)
VALUES
(
STRUCT(['TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT4']))

but i got the following error message:

Value has type STRUCT<ARRAY> which cannot be inserted into column paragraphs, which has type STRUCT<list ARRAY<STRUCT>> at [6:3]

What changes should I make on my query?